# Find the value of the sum with accuracy up to $o(1)$.

Tags: calculus, euler-mascheroni-constant, euler-maclaurin

Consider the sum $S_n = 1 + \frac13 + \frac15 + ... + \frac{1}{2n-1}$. How do we find its sum with accuracy up to $o(1)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ S_n = H_{2n}-\frac{1}{2}H_n = \log(2n)-\frac{1}{2}\log(n)+\frac{\gamma}{2}+o(1) = \frac{1}{2}\log(n)+\log(2)+\frac{\gamma}{2}+o(1) $$
follows from the well-known asymptotics for harmonic numbers.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, there also must be a half of Euler gamma.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen: correct, thank you. Now fixed.